# T5Tokenizer requires the SentencePiece library but it was not found in your environment

Tags: huggingface-transformers, google-colaboratory

I am trying to explore [T5](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/t5.html#)

this is the code

```
!pip install transformers
from transformers import T5Tokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration
qa_input = """question: What is the capital of Syria? context: The name "Syria" historically referred to a wider region,
 broadly synonymous with the Levant, and known in Arabic as al-Sham. The modern state encompasses the sites of several ancient 
 kingdoms and empires, including the Eblan civilization of the 3rd millennium BC. Aleppo and the capital city Damascus are 
 among the oldest continuously inhabited cities in the world."""
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained('t5-small')
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('t5-small')
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(qa_input, return_tensors="pt")  # Batch size 1
outputs = model.generate(input_ids)
output_str = tokenizer.decode(outputs.reshape(-1))
```

I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-2-8d24c6a196e4> in <module>()
      5  kingdoms and empires, including the Eblan civilization of the 3rd millennium BC. Aleppo and the capital city Damascus are
      6  among the oldest continuously inhabited cities in the world."""
----> 7 tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained('t5-small')
      8 model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('t5-small')
      9 input_ids = tokenizer.encode(qa_input, return_tensors="pt")  # Batch size 1

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/file_utils.py in requires_sentencepiece(obj)
    521     name = obj.__name__ if hasattr(obj, "__name__") else obj.__class__.__name__
    522     if not is_sentencepiece_available():
--> 523         raise ImportError(SENTENCEPIECE_IMPORT_ERROR.format(name))
    524 
    525 

ImportError: 
T5Tokenizer requires the SentencePiece library but it was not found in your environment. Checkout the instructions on the
installation page of its repo: https://github.com/google/sentencepiece#installation and follow the ones
that match your environment.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

after that I install sentencepiece library as was suggested like this:

```
!pip install transformers
!pip install sentencepiece

from transformers import T5Tokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration
qa_input = """question: What is the capital of Syria? context: The name "Syria" historically referred to a wider region,
 broadly synonymous with the Levant, and known in Arabic as al-Sham. The modern state encompasses the sites of several ancient 
 kingdoms and empires, including the Eblan civilization of the 3rd millennium BC. Aleppo and the capital city Damascus are 
 among the oldest continuously inhabited cities in the world."""
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained('t5-small')
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('t5-small')
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(qa_input, return_tensors="pt")  # Batch size 1
outputs = model.generate(input_ids)
output_str = tokenizer.decode(outputs.reshape(-1))
```

but I got another issue:

> Some weights of the model checkpoint at t5-small were not used when
> initializing T5ForConditionalGeneration:
> ['decoder.block.0.layer.1.EncDecAttention.relative_attention_bias.weight']
>
> - This IS expected if you are initializing T5ForConditionalGeneration from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another
>   architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model
>   from a BertForPreTraining model).
> - This IS NOT expected if you are initializing T5ForConditionalGeneration from the checkpoint of a model that you
>   expect to be exactly identical (initializing a
>   BertForSequenceClassification model from a
>   BertForSequenceClassification model).

so I did not understand what is going on, any explanation?

Comment: ok i will add more details

Comment: The other message is not an error but a warning. I am not sure how I can help you here as it is pretty self-explanatory. Can you be more specific about which part you don't understand?

Comment: yes I find out that after asking the question, sorry!

Comment: @cronoik I did not understand what is the consequences of this warning and if I can continue working normally after that warning or not and how to differentiate between encoded question ids and encoded context ids

Comment: @cronoik and if I have batched  (question, context) pairs how to use model with batches

Comment: Please update your question (and the code) and include what is currently not working or what is unclear for you.

Comment: On the 
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained('t5-small')
line, I get
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 8):

I used these two command and this working fine for me!

```
!pip install datasets transformers[sentencepiece]
!pip install sentencepiece
```

Comment: is this `datsets` or `datasets`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue. I also observe the second output. It is just a warning that the library shows. You fixed your actual issue. Do not worry about the warning.

Answer (score 0):

> Use:

```
!pip uninstall transformers
!pip install transformers==3.2.0
!pip install transformers[sentencepiece]
!pip install sentencepiece
```

**> It is crucial to make sure to restart your runtime before running again, otherwise the statements above will be helpless!**

Answer (score 0):

On Apple Silicon macs try this:

```
brew install cmake
brew install pkg-config 
pip install sentencepiece
```